Hobbies and travelling
My hobby is to travel, the following hints lead you to my next destination.
What is my destination? And how do you know?
Hints:

Gsv kozxv rh mlg xolhv gl gsv hvz.

Gsv kozxv dv ziv ollprmt uli rm vfilkv.

Rg rh pmldm uli z yvzfgrufo oryizib.

Gsv wzmfyv uoldh gsilfts gsv xlfmgib gl dsrxs gsv kozxv yvolmth

Rg rh pmldm uli z yrt all drgs z xzhgov zmw tifnkb kvlkov




This is

A riddle that is encoded with the Atbash Cipher - decoding gives:

1. The place is not close to the sea.
2. The place we are looking for in europe.
3. It is known for a beautiful library.
4. The danube flows through the country to which the place belongs
5. It is known for a big zoo with a castle and grumpy people

And the answer is

Vienna

As it is the capital of Austria, a landlocked European country, with the Danube river flowing throw it. It is famous for the Schönbrunn Zoo in the Schönbrunn Palace gardens, and the Austrian National Library.

